# Should I be using a promise? FIrebase function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function that is correctly collecting the five elements I have stored in a firebase database. but when I return the value back to the calling function I'm getting undefined. I added the timeout to see if the data was not coming in back in time, but both console.logs print out undefined.

I'm trying to understand what I'm missing.

```
function  getSpecialDbData() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      var specialsData = [],
        i = 0;
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        specialsData[i] = childData;
        i++;
      });
      console.log(specialsData); //this works
      return specialsData;
    });
  };
```

It's being called with the following code

```
  let specialData =  getSpecialDbData();
  setTimeout(function(){     console.log(specialData);}, 5000);
  console.log(specialData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a value from a function *from within another function callback*.

Bear in mind also that Firebase APIs are asynchronous, so the call to once() returns immediately, before any value is fetched.  This means you can't return a value from Realtime Database as the result of a function.  You have to handle the result entirely within the callback (or returned promise from once()).

[Read more here](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93) about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous, and what to expect from them.